# How to import tweenmax files to my project

Tags: actionscript, flash-cs5

while im working on simple animation like text rolling.. in that i created external xml for menus. As im new to flash im learning it from tutorial, but its not clear. I download tweenmax rar file. i dont know how to import that file into my project. guide me

Comment: hello friends now i import that file but have some problem in running..its show Error Definition.com.greenstock could not found.. please help me for this.

Comment: there are two ways you can do this: 1. you can unzip [downloaded package](http://www.greensock.com/as/greensock-as3.zip) and make sure the **com** is in the same folder as the .fla file that uses it. 2. you can use the ActionScript settings classpath option - which looks a bit like [this](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/images/flexflash.gif) to add the greensock code to you current document's class path.

Comment: one silly mistake i did.. i didnt include .fla file inside the com floder... now i got it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

when you want to use a tween class. 
either save the FLA file in the same directory of the tweenlibrary so the .com folder(tween library) would be present next to your  flash project file or go into the classpath of your document and link it there, your best to look at the documentation for this method through the provider of the tween class.